# useEffect and redux a cache trial not working

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a rather complex setup and am new to React with Hooks and Redux.

My setup:

- I have a component, which when first mounted, should fetch data. Later this data should be updated at a given interval but not too often.
- I added useRef to avoid a cascade of calls when one store changes. Without useEffect is called for every possible change of the stores linked in its array.
- The data is a list and rather complex to fetch, as I first have to map a name to an ID and
  then fetch its value.
- To avoid doing this over and over again for a given "cache time" I tried to implement a cache using redux.
- The whole thing is wrapped inside a useEffect function.
- I use different "stores" and "reducer" for different pieces.

Problem:

- The cache is written but during the useEffect cycle, changes are not readable. Even processing the same ISIN once again the cache returns no HIT as it is empty.
- Really complex implementation. It dawns on me, something is really messed up in my setup.

Research so far:

- I know there are libs for caching redux, I do want to understand the system before using one.
- Thunk and Saga seem to be something but - same as above plus - I do not get the concept and would love to have fewer dependencies.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Component - useEffect**

```
const calculateRef = useRef(true);  

useEffect(() => {
  if (calculateRef.current) {
    calculateRef.current = false;

    const fetchData = async (
      dispatch: AppDispatch,
      stocks: IStockArray,
      transactions: ITransactionArray,
      cache: ICache
    ): Promise<IDashboard> => {
      const dashboardStock = aggregate(stocks, transactions);

      // Fetch notation
      const stockNotation = await Promise.all(
        dashboardStock.stocks.map(async (stock) => {
          const notationId = await getXETRANotation(
            stock.isin,
            cache,
            dispatch
          );
          return {
            isin: stock.isin,
            notationId,
          };
        })
      );

      // Fetch quote
      const stockQuote = await Promise.all(
        stockNotation.map(async (stock) => {
          const price = await getQuote(stock.notationId, cache, dispatch);
          return {
            isin: stock.isin,
            notationId: stock.notationId,
            price,
          };
        })
      );

      for (const s of dashboardStock.stocks) {
        for (const q of stockQuote) {
          if (s.isin === q.isin) {
            s.notationId = q.notationId;
            s.price = q.price;

            // Calculate current price for stock
            if (s.quantity !== undefined && s.price !== undefined) {
              dashboardStock.totalCurrent += s.quantity * s.price;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      dispatch({
        type: DASHBOARD_PUT,
        payload: dashboardStock,
      });

      return dashboardStock;
    };

    fetchData(dispatch, stocks, transactions, cache);
  }
}, [dispatch, stocks, transactions, cache]);
```

**Action - async fetch action with cache:**

```
export const getXETRANotation = async (
  isin: string,
  cache: ICache,
  dispatch: AppDispatch
): Promise<number> => {
  Logger.debug(`getXETRANotation: ${isin}`);

  if (CACHE_ENABLE) {
    const cacheTimeExceeding = new Date().getTime() + CACHE_NOTATION;
    if (
      isin in cache.notation &&
      cache.notation[isin].created < cacheTimeExceeding
    ) {
      Logger.debug(
        `getXETRANotation - CACHE HIT: ${isin} (${cache.notation[isin].created} < ${cacheTimeExceeding} current)`
      );
      return cache.notation[isin].notationId;
    }
  }

  // FETCH FANCY AXIOS RESULT
  const axiosRESULT = ...

  if (CACHE_ENABLE) {
    Logger.debug(`getXETRANotation - CACHE STORE: ${isin}: ${axiosRESULT}`);
    dispatch({
      type: CACHE_NOTATION_PUT,
      payload: {
        isin,
        notationId: axiosRESULT,
        created: new Date().getTime(),
      },
    });
  }

  //FANCY AXIOS RESULT
  return axiosRESULT;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to write your own caching logic with refs. Instead use useReducer with useMemo for memoized reducers.

Comment: Do you have an der example and is this usable globally in other components?

Comment: Yes you can use it globally with context.
useReducer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer 
useMemo: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo 
useContext: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Maybe its me but does this make sense when I already have redux?